# arcpy, ExportToSVG using paths

Tags: export, arcpy, svg

I want to export part of the map into (very big) SVG file. First I tried to do this using REST API:
`https://*server*/ArcGIS/rest/services/General/Etages/MapServer/export`.
This worked, the SVG file contains `<path>` tags describing all polygons I have on map and `<text>` tags describing all the labels. The only problem is that max SVG file size is limited to 4096x4096 pixels.

So I switched to python:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('d:\\maps\\etages.mxd')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.mapping.ExportToSVG(mxd, 'd:\\maps\\etages.svg', df, 256*30, 256*30)
del mxd
```

I can export bigger maps this way, but the problem is that out SVG file is rendered using `<image>` tags. Is it possible to force `arcpy` to export SVG as real polygons/text, not prerendered images?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the the `VECTORIZE_BITMAP` parameter of ExportToSVG

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToSVG(mxd, 'd:\\maps\\etages.svg', df, 256*30, 256*30, "", "", "", "VECTORIZE_BITMAP")
```